# what's causing "error 193 %1 is not a valid win32 app"

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I know this question has already been asked but this is different. I'm generating a 2D array of spiral numbers and a vector of prime numbers. The goal of this program is to find the ratio of prime numbers on the diagonals of the spiral numbers array. I've tested both arrays and they work just fine. I even printed the 2d array for small values of G to see the spiral numbers and It's working. What I don't understand is why do I get this error when I choose values of N more than 8000. (N and G are names of variables)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

//Error 193 %1 is not a viable win32 app 
constexpr unsigned long long  N = 7800; //for values of N above 8000??
constexpr unsigned long long G = 2*N + 1; 
static unsigned long long arr[G][G];
//we only need primes up to G 
constexpr unsigned long long P_LIMIT = 50000;//more than enough
std::vector < unsigned long long > prime(P_LIMIT);  

void generate_primes (void)
{
prime[0] = 2, prime[1] = 3, prime[2] = 5; 
unsigned long long index = 3; 
unsigned long long p; 

for (p = 7; index < 50000; p += 2)
{
    int isPrime = 1; 
    unsigned long long test_limit = (unsigned long long) sqrt(p); 

    for (unsigned long long i = 1; prime[i] <= test_limit; i++)
    {
        if (p % prime[i] == 0) 
        {
            isPrime = 0; 
            break; 
        }
    }

    if(isPrime) prime[index++] = p; 
}

}

void fill_spiral (void){
unsigned long long i = 0, j = 2*N, k, n = G, l; 

for (l = 1; l <= N; l++)
{
    arr[i][j] = n*n; 
    arr[i][i] = arr[i][j] - n + 1; 
    arr[j][i] = arr[i][j] - 2*n + 2; 
    arr[j][j] = arr[i][j] - 3*n + 3; 

    for (k = i+1; k < j; k++)
    {
        arr[i][k] = arr[i][k-1] + 1; 
        arr[j][k] = arr[j][k-1] - 1; 
        arr[k][i] = arr[k-1][i] - 1; 
    }

    for (k = j-1; k > i; k--)
    {
        arr[k][j] = arr[k+1][j] - 1; 
    }

    ++i, --j, n -= 2; 
}

}
//diagonals of arr[G][G] 
int prime_ratio (void)
{
unsigned long long count = 0;
double ratio = 0.62;
unsigned long long side = 3, d = 2.0*side - 1;    
for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= N; i++) 
{
    unsigned long long test = sqrt(arr[N+i][N+i]); 
    int isPrime = 1;  
    for (unsigned long long index = 0; prime[index] <= test; index++)
    {
        if (arr[N+i][N+i] % prime[index] == 0)
        {
            isPrime = 0; 
            break; 
        }                 
    }

    if (isPrime) ++count; 

    test = sqrt(arr[N+i][N-i]), isPrime = 1; 
    for (unsigned long long index = 0; prime[index] <= test; index++)
    {
        if (arr[N+i][N-i] % prime[index] == 0)
        {
            isPrime = 0; 
            break;     
        }        
    }

    if (isPrime) ++count;  

    test = sqrt(arr[N-i][N+i]), isPrime = 1; 
    for (unsigned long long index = 0; prime[index] <= test; index++)
    {
        if (arr[N-i][N+i] % prime[index] == 0)
        {
            isPrime = 0; 
            break;     
        }        
    }

    if (isPrime) ++count; 

    test = sqrt(arr[N-i][N-i]), isPrime = 1; 
    for (unsigned long long index = 0; prime[index] <= test; index++)
    {
        if (arr[N-i][N-i] % prime[index] == 0)
        {
            isPrime = 0; 
            break;     
        }        
    }

    if (isPrime) ++count; 

    ratio = (double) count / d; 
    std::cout << std::setprecision(15) <<ratio<< "\t" <<side<<std::endl; 
    side += 2, d = 2*side - 1;       
    }

//std::cout << side << std::endl; 
return 0;     
}

int main (void)
{
std::cout << "generating primes..." << '\n'; 
generate_primes(); 
arr[N][N] = 1;
std::cout<< "generating spiral numbers array..." << '\n';  
fill_spiral();  
std::cout<< "solving ratio problem..." << '\n'; 
prime_ratio();  
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is caused by use of huge global array `arr[G][G]`. If `N` is 9000 then this array size would be 9000 * 2 * 9000 * 2 * 8 = 2 592 000 000 - more than two GB. Actually VS2015 refuses to compile this code saying that array size is too large. Try allocating it on the heap instead.